# Redirection and piping in Windows environment

Tags: windows, redirect, batch-processing, piping

I wonder if there's a way to construct a **one-liner** which does the job of these two consecutive commands:
`echo %path% > mypath.txt`
`notepad mypath.txt`
Something like `notepad < (echo %path% > mypath.txt)` doesn't do the trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo %path% > mypath.txt&notepad mypath.txt
```

should work for you.